# Input values missing from a input Text

Tags: laravel

I have this controller who grab the two text fiel values that the user enter before clicking save. Everything going good till i check the values.. nothing happen it seems that the input request doesn't work

Where i'm doing wrong ? i don't get the values entered for "resultat_domicile" and "resultat_visiteur" . thanks a lot in advance if someone could help

here the controller :

```
public function addResultat(Request $request  , $id){

        $rencontre = Rencontre::findOrFail($id);

        $rencontre->resultat_domicile = $request->input('resultat_domicile');
        $rencontre->resultat_visiteur = $request->input('resultat_visiteur');

        dd($rencontre);

    }
```

here my view :

```
 {!!  Form::open(array('route' => array('add.resultat', $rencontre->id)))!!}

                @foreach($rencontres as $rencontre)


                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                                <p class="h4">{{$rencontre->compet->lb_compet}}</p>
                                <p class="h4 text-light-blue">{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($rencontre->dt_rencontre)->format('d/m/Y')}}</p>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <h2 class="pull-right"><div class="fa fa-shield pull-right"></div>{{$rencontre->equipe_domicile->lb_equipe}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        {!! Form::text('resultat_domicile', null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ex: 20 points']) !!}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                                        <span class="h2">-</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        {!! Form::text('resultat_visiteur', null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ex: 20 points']) !!}
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <h2 class="pull-left"><div class="fa fa-shield pull-left"></div>{{$rencontre->equipe_visiteur->lb_equipe}}</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        @endforeach

                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                {!! Form::submit('Enregistrer', ['class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg center-block']) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Try `dd($request->resultat_domicile);` and see what happens. Let me know if that gave the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've shown complete view. You need to submit the form to get values, but you're just creating a simple link.

Make sure you're opening the form with `Form::open()` and submitting the form with submit button, like `Form::submit()`

Comment: sorry haha !!!! i forgot to try this . thanks i updated the code if someone have the same problem . thanks a lot again

Comment: the only problem now when i click on save i get the value but if i have many ids it's take only the first one ! it's seems my foreach is not in the right place

Comment: i mean it's look like a form inside a loop and when i click on save , all the button is clicked in the save time and i get only the first object , i would like to save on each object inside the loop

Comment: Then move the form's open and close tags and submit button outside the loop. Also, change text field names to something like `resultat_domicile[]`. In a controller you'll get arrays then.

Comment: if i move the form open with $rencontre->id i get Undefined variable: rencontre .

Comment: i update the blade view in the post . i really don't know i do proceed :/